# taking the documentation out of the controller swagger blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-2.0, rails-api

I am trying to take my documentation out of my controller not sure if this possible and how to do it.

so sample Controller has this

`class VI::SomeController < ActionController::API
      include Swagger::Blocks
    end`

in my Apidocs controller this is the definition

```
class ApidocsController < ActionController::API

  include Swagger::Blocks

  swagger_root do
    key :swagger, '2.0'
    info do
      key :version, '1.0.0'
      key :title, 'Loanplus API'
      key :description, 'Loanplus API Specification'
    end
    # tag do
    #   key :name, 'mortgage_loans'
    #   key :description, 'Get mortgage loans'
    # end

    key :host, HOST
    key :basePath, '/api/v1'
    key :consumes, ['application/json']
    key :produces, ['application/json']

    # security_definition :api_key do
    #   key :type, :apiKey
    #   key :name, :api_key
    #   key :in, :query
    # end
    #
    # security do
    #   key :api_key, []
    # end
  end

  # A list of all classes that have swagger_* declarations.
  SWAGGERED_CLASSES = [V1::LpDeveloperReferralsController, self].freeze

  def index
    result = Swagger::Blocks.build_root_json(SWAGGERED_CLASSES)
    render json: result
  end
end
```

How can i put the documentation somewhere else. I tried putting the documentation to a concern and calling it from there but doesnt work. Any other options